# addEventListener issue on <a>

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm going through what must be a really simple issue here, I'm just not seeing it.

I'm trying to set up an event Listener on some specifics `<a>`, depending on its title. If "title" is equals to "Platform", then I'm adding a console.log("check");.

I'm adding several console.logs(); to see what's not working, and it seems to be only about the click on the button, it just won't trigger...

My button ( I have four with title == "Platform" in my page) :

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="tracking_addtocart" title="Platform" onclick="MiniCart.add(305008900); $.fancybox.close();" data-tracking-enabled="true" data-check="true"><span>Checkout</span></a>
```

My code :

```
<script language="javascript">
var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

function eventCheck (elem){ 
    console.log('eventCheck Triggered');
    elem.addEventListener("click", function (){
        console.log('Check');
        }
    );
}

function Check() {
    for (var i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
        if (anchor[i].getAttribute('title') == "Platform") {
            console.log("Found one");
            anchor[i].setAttribute('data-check','true');
            eventCheck(anchor[i]);   
        }
    }

}

setTimeout(Check, 3000)

</script>
```

I'd really appreciate if you guys could give me hand.

Hugo

PS: I'm not a developper, I just have some very basic skills in JS.

Comment: In `onclick="MiniCart.add(305008900); $.fancybox.close();" `, what those functions exactly doing...?

Comment: Hi, they trigger a function to dynamically add a product to cart. Do you think it could be messing with my event ?

Comment: I added your code into this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/78r0knhv/ and it works as it should (note, I removed the `onclick="MiniCart.add(305008900); $.fancybox.close();"`since I don't have those funtions.

Comment: @HugoP. It could be a problem because when i try to give some dummy function in `onclick="someFunc()"`, then `addEventListener callback` gets called... You can check this.. http://jsfiddle.net/0dq83qge/

Comment: Yes I guess it's coming from there, as they are being triggered at the same time. I'll try to add setTimeout to my event listener to see if it changes anything.